# vue list render template

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to bulid a button when clicked and show a list under itself,
in the list,I want show a icon and wording,the word is after the icon,
how should I do?

```
<button
      type="button"
      class="
        lang-options-button
      "
      @click="langMember(index)"
    >
      <icon
        class="w-auto h-6 hover:text-primary-dark flex items-center"
        icon-name="icon_en"
        title="切換語言"
      />
    </button>
    <!-- lang box -->
    <ul
      class="
        lang-options-list
        w-40
        py-2
        bg-white
        rounded
        shadow
        absolute
        top-10
        right-0
        z-10
      "
      v-show="displayLang[index]"
    >
      <li>
        <button
        >
        <icon icon-name="icon_en"/> English (US)
        </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button 
        >
        <icon icon-name="icon_cn"/> 繁體中文
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

when I doing like this, the icon is above the word,
seems like icon on a line and the wording is another line

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may provide the css for <icon> tag. You may look into examples below to achieve your requirement:

[display: inline-block](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), to displays an element as an inline-level block container. The element itself is formatted as an inline element, but you can apply height and width values. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=inline-block)

And also,

[CSS Grid Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=inline-block):
[image]